# How to debug missing Proxyregistration?

Tags: c#

I have a windows Form application here, and got following Error:

> Missing Proxyregistration for IID {{EAC04BC0-3791-11D2-BB95-0060977B464C}.

Then I got a stack trace:

```
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid&amp;amp; clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid&amp;amp; iid)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.StringSource..ctor(String[] strings)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.SetAutoComplete(Boolean reset)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidCastException: Schnittstelle nicht registriert
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to read the stack trace. Can someone give me a hand - and can describe, how I debug this error with best practices?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is some code. the last line drops the Exception.

```
    private void pbbtpisaddhtcshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
       
        mainForm.gpbpishotelfilter.Visible = false;
        mainForm.pbbtpisnhotelfilter.Image = GDISClient.Properties.Resources.filter_show_30;
        mainForm.tbpishtccodes.Focus();
        if (mainForm.tbpishtccodes.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            string test = mainForm.tbpishtccodes.Text.Replace(' ', '\0');
            string[] htcsplit = test.Split(',');

            foreach (string item in htcsplit)
            {
                mainForm.lbpishtcall.SelectedIndex = (mainForm.lbpishtcall.FindString(item));
                if (mainForm.lbpishtcall.FindString(item) >= 0)
                {
                    mainForm.lbpishtcadded.Items.Add(mainForm.lbpishtcall.SelectedItem);
                    mainForm.lbpishtcall.Items.Remove(mainForm.lbpishtcall.SelectedItem);
                }
            }
            mainForm.lbpishtcall.ClearSelected();
            mainForm.lbpishtcadded.ClearSelected();
        }
        mainForm.tbpishtcsuche.Focus();
        mainForm.gbpishtcadd.Visible = true;
    }
```

the gpbishtcadd is a groupbox, which are going to be filled by background workers.

After the backgroundworker has done its RunWorkerCompletet event, it should be done.

I think its possible, that the backgroundworker is not finished at the time, the button is pressed, and the groupbox is shown, so maybe its crashing in here.

Comment: We are not psychic, we can't do anything unless you show us the code that's causing this to happen.

Comment: Show your autocomplete settings please ([related link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85f6c62a-8e80-4ea4-b41c-468c0c695b07/interface-not-registered-failed-to-find-proxy-registration-for-iid))